# Is YouTube API dependent on a specific browser?

Tags: browser, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube API to search for YouTube videos using the yt_search() function. I am wondering whether searches made using the API are dependent on or unaffected by local browser history or cache and, if so, from which browser?

Note: I recognize this is more of a back-end question and not code-based per se, but would appreciate any and all responses from anyone with YouTube API expertise/experience. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify more: Why you think that it is affected by something? Don't you get the same results every time you call yt_search()? On a different computer? With the same/different google account logged in? What parameters you use? The link to the documentation is this? https://rdrr.io/cran/tuber/man/yt_search.html --> that points to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list ? Other links?

Comment: Thanks @BitLauncher for your response. I'm not sure if it is affected by it, but simply speculating. I recognize that YouTube search results and, likewise, Google search results are influenced by one's search history associated with their Google account and local browser history. I guess, assuming same Google account is used to register and log into the YouTube API account, the search results should be the same every time. I'm just wondering whether it's agnostic of local browser history or cache stored on the computer?

Comment: I found this link here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth and it says the API is platform-agnostic. My goal is to use the API to replicate searching YouTube on incognito; hence, I was wondering the potential dependence of YouTube API on any specific browser and its stored history or cache. Hope this clarifies, thanks for your help.

Comment: From a developer's perspective, unfortunately, the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint is entirely opaque: that is that there's no official doc from Google/YouTube which provide inside into the workings of this endpoint. It's not even clear -- as per the official docs again (however, other sources may well exist) -- that `Search.list` is *exactly the same thing* as the search functionality within YouTube's Web UI.

Comment: One may only guess (and test) the behavior of `Search.list` by gathering together info from third-party sources -- see, for example, the Wikipedia article on [*Personalized search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalized_search).